# Weight paint issue

Tags: weight-painting

It's been awhile since I used blender.
I'm using left click select with blender 2.8.

If I select just the mesh and go to weight paint I can right click on the model to paint, but I can't left click the bones (I have to use the menu on the right) and I can't move the bones to see how the weight paint has effected the model.

Though if I select the armature, shift select the mesh and then go to weight paint - I can left click the bones and move them but right click brings up a menu instead of painting.

Can you not both weight paint and select/move the bones at the same time or do I have to keep swapping between both methods?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to enable or disable the Lock Object Modes in the top menu bar > Edit? Also have you tried cmd right click in the Preferences > Keymap > Preferences > Select With > Right?

Comment: Hi, thanks looks like it was the lock objects mode